# Check if all elements in array are present in a string as words using regular expressions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have used existing Javascript functions that I found online but I need more control and I think regular expressions will allow it using flags to control if case sensitive or not, multiline etc.

```
var words=['one','two','cat','oranges'];
var string='The cat ate two oranges and one mouse.';
check=string.match(pattern);
pattern=???;
if(check!==null){
  //string matches all array elements
}else{
  //string does not match all array  words
}
```

what would the pattern be and if it can be constructed using javascript using the array as a source?

***I will need to place the same function on the backend in PHP and so it would be easier just to create a regular expression and use it instead of looping and finding alternatives for this to work in PHP.

***I would love to have as many options including changes, replace, count and regular expressions are meant for this. And on the plus side the speed should be better using regex instead of looping(search the whole text for every element in the array) specially in case of a long array and a long string.

Comment: `hasAllWords = words.every(word => string.includes(word))`

Comment: you can search for ```String.prototype.includes()``` and what you need to is loop the words array with this function.

Comment: _"...using regular expressions"_ - Why?

Comment: I might need to place the same function on the backend in PHP and using regex would make it pretty easy plus dynamically I would like to control whether i move on the new lines or on the whole string, case insensitive etc.

Comment: You can easily replicate the functionality in PHP using array functions. It'll be just 2-3 lines of code.

Comment: I do not know however just as any other function I would love to have as many options including changes, replace, count  and regular expressions are meant for this. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var words=['one','two','cat','oranges'];
let string='The cat ate two oranges and one mouse.';

     words=words.map(function(value,index){return '(?=(.)*?\\b('+value+')\\b)'; }).join('');
     let pattern=new RegExp(`${words}((.)+)`,'g');

if(string.match(pattern)!==null){
  //string matches all elements
}else{
  //string does not match all words
}
```

It will look for the exact word match, and you will have the extra control you wanted using regex flags for case insensitive..

if you want to test it or adjust it you can do it here:
[doregex.com](https://doregex.com/?urlconstruction=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#crumbstart)

You can use the same regex to make changes within the text using a callback function.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect you saved my day. Bless you!!!!!!!!

Comment: plus I did not know you can use variables in javascript regex string and very usefull link you gave me. Thanks again

Comment: *Note that you cannot replace the backtick( ` ) with any other type of quotes(simple ' or double ") or the expression will fail.

Comment: @Manuela79: Please consider accepting/upvoting an answer that helped you.

Comment: Hi, I have tried but it said I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote

Answer (score 0):

You can create [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) objects from your strings, this will allow you further control over case sensitivity etc.

For example:

```js
const patterns = [ 'ONE','two','cat','oranges'];
const string = 'The cat ate two oranges and one mouse.';
// Match in a case sensitive way
const result = patterns.every(pattern => new RegExp(pattern, 'i').test(string));
console.log("All patterns match:", result);
```

Comment: I will need to place the same function on the backend in PHP and so it would be easier just to create a regular expression and use it instead of looping and finding alternatives for this to work in PHP. But thank you for your attention. I am happy to use the answer with "let pattern=new RegExp(`${words}((.)+)`,'g');"